# Is this GSV sentence valid?

Tags: gps, nmea

According to the [specifications](https://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#GSV), GSV sentence contains information about satellite. But in this sentence (extracted from my Sierra receiver):

```
$GPGSV,3,3,11,04,,,,08,04,262,,10,06,151,*75
```

If I understand right:

- 3-> Number of sentences
- 3-> Index (3rd sentence)
- 11 -> Satellites being tracked
- 04 -> PRN1
- ,, -> Elevation Null
- ,, -> Azimuth Null
- ,,    -> SNR Null
- 08 -> PRN2
- 04 -> Elevation ?
- 262 ->Azimuth
- ,, -> SNR Null
- 10 -> PRN3
- 06 -> Elevation?
- 151 -> Azimuth

**Where is SNR for PRN3? If it is null...why are the commas missing??**

*75 -> Checksum

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

The *GPRMC & GPGGA decoder* (https://rl.se/gprmc) tells us that `$GPGSV,3,3,11,04,,,,08,04,262,,10,06,151,*75` is a malformed input string, so probably the sentence is not valid.

You could try also double-check with the *NMEA 0183 sentence parser/builder* from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/279647/NMEA-0183-sentence-parser-builder which reports it supports GP talker and GSV sentence